# Can't run Visual Studio Code on Fedora: "Permission denied" error on /proc/version

Tags: permissions, fedora, visual-studio-code

I had successfully installed Visual Studio Code on Fedora 33, but when I run it says this error:

```
grep: /proc/version: Permission denied
```

- Somewhere on the internet, I found that you have to execute this

  ```
  cat proc/version
  ```

  but it says

  ```
  cat: version: Permission denied
  ```
- Then I tried

  ```
  nano proc/version
  ```

  but it failed to write.
- I tried `chmod: cannot access 'version': Permission denied`.
- Running

  ```
  ls -l /proc/version
  ```

  give me

  ```
  ls: cannot access '/proc/version': Permission denied
  ```

What do I do now?

Comment: Post the output of "ls -l /proc/version". The file should have permissions "-r--r--r-- 1 root root" so you shouldn't be able to edit the file unless you're root. And it contains the Linux kernal version so you don't want to edit it. It's essentially the same information as using "uname -a". Maybe there's kernel conflict with Visual Studio Code? Did you install Visual Studio Code using rpm?

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/proc/version': Permission denied` is the result of the first command but the second command says `Linux localhost 4.14.190-perf-ga99a091 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jul 31 03:46:50 CST 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`. I installed it through`dnf`.

Comment: Okay, you should be able to type "cat /proc/version" and "ls -l /proc/version". You may have a problem with installation.

Comment: The problem is not that you can't change permission. You don't need to, and you can't edit it. It is not a real file. **Add the output of `findmnt` to the question.**

Comment: You seem to be missing some `/`s

Comment: You're not running this under Docker, or some other container system, are you

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is a missing `/` at the beginning.

You want to access the absolute path `/proc/version`, while by using `proc/version` a path relative to the current directory is accessed. In return that only works, when your current working directory (which can be found out using `pwd`) is `/`.

From a permission point of view, `/proc/version` usually is world readable. Thus running `cat /proc/version` should just work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case, after all he has these errors `ls: cannot access '/proc/version': Permission denied` and `grep: /proc/version: Permission denied`. Admittedly in some of the attempts the `/` was omitted, but that doesn't seem to be the initial problem.